# Display header menu in IWD one page checkout extension

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I want to display my header menu but it is not showing on onepage checkout page. I have tried this methods below but not working 
Please help me find the solution.

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
<referenceBlock name="navigation.sections" remove="false"/>
```

In the `onepage_index_index.xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find an answer here.
[Magento 2.2 IWD Onepage Checkout Header Issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/214816/magento-2-2-iwd-onepage-checkout-issue/221390#221390)

Please upvote, so other can take advantage.