# Magento 2.2 IWD Onepage Checkout Issue

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento2.2

I have installed and enable one-page checkout extension by IWD Agency it shows correctly but removes my theme header and footer how to prevent it and Show my header footer as it was before.
Here I can attach a screen shot.Please review.
[image]
Thanks in advance,
Abdullah Shahid

Answer (score 1):

Please go to this file path

```
IWD/Opc/view/frontend/layout/onepage_index_index.xml
```

update code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

to

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

It is done.

Please mark as useful so other can also take advantage.

Comment: Im using the Ultimo Theme and this did not have an effect

Answer (score 0):

there maybe some other issue but yes it is common that sometime we put layout attribute value 'checkout', change it to 'column'. Might be it works else you have to check it [magento extensions](https://www.aalogics.com/magento-extensions) from here.

Comment: please describe more what you want to said