# Magento 2: Display header and footer menu in IWD one page checkout extension

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout

I'm trying to add the header and footer to a template in an extension called iwd one page checkout.

Please note the solution posted here does not seem to have any effect:

[Magento 2.2 IWD Onepage Checkout Issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/214816/magento-2-2-iwd-onepage-checkout-issue/221390?newreg=4b223f89671d4cc097d20fef33ad0bf3)

I've identified the layout file as:

`magento\app\code\IWD\Opc\view\frontend\layout\onepage_index_index.xml`

which contains

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      layout="checkout"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_index_index"/>
    <head>
        <css src="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,700italic,700" src_type="url"/>
        <css src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" src_type="url"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="iwd_opc_ga_ab" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">IWD_Opc::onepage.phtml</argument>
            </action>
            <block class="Magento\GiftMessage\Block\Cart\GiftOptions"
                   name="checkout.gift_options"
                   template="IWD_Opc::gift_options.phtml"
                   cacheable="false">
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                   name="iwd.opc.popup"
                   template="IWD_Opc::popup.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

What I did was try to add the following line

```
<block class="Redgiant\Xstore\Block\Template" name="xstore_header" template="Magento_Theme::html/xstore_header.phtml" before="main.content"/>
```

from:

```
magento\app\design\frontend\Redgiant\xstore\Magento_Theme\page_layout\override\base\1column.xml
```

However, that has had no effect. I know editing the file onepage_index_index.xml does work as altering the includes in the head carry through.

I think it may be something to do with the class and template references but I'm not sure.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: You want to add header and footer section to your checkout page, right?

Comment: Hi Sumit, many thanks for your reply. Yes that's right

Comment: Are you using any third party theme for your website?

Comment: Yes, it's this one here: https://themeforest.net/item/xstore-responsive-magento-2-theme/23392534

Comment: Is it porto theme??

Comment: I'm not sure, there is no reference to 'porto' in the theme

Comment: Ok, I've faced same issue while customizing the OPC for my website.

Comment: Ah I see, what worked for you?

Comment: I can share the solution with you by tommorow. Is it okay with you?

Comment: Yes that would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by following the below steps.

Copy `app/code/IWD/Opc/view/frontend/layout/onepage_index_index.xml` and place it under `app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[your_theme]/IWD_Opc/layout/onepage_index_index.xml` with below content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_index_index"/>
    <head>
        <css src="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,700italic,700" src_type="url"/>
        <css src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" src_type="url"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="iwd_opc_ga_ab" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">IWD_Opc::onepage.phtml</argument>
            </action>
            <block class="Magento\GiftMessage\Block\Cart\GiftOptions"
                   name="checkout.gift_options"
                   template="IWD_Opc::gift_options.phtml"
                   cacheable="false">
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                   name="iwd.opc.popup"
                   template="IWD_Opc::popup.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Also, create checkout_index_index.xml under `app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[your_theme]/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml` with below content.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>      
        <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />
        <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false" />
        <referenceBlock name="nav-sections" remove="false"/>
        <referenceBlock name="footer_block" remove="false"/>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Run below commands

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: Absolutely perfect Sumit, that work perfectly. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome :)